# 5 numbers equal 23

Tags: algorithm, combinations, pseudocode

How can I check whether 5 given numbers and mathematical operations (+, -, *)could be arranged to get the result of 23?

For instance:

**1 1 1 1 1 –– Impossible**

**1 2 3 4 5 –– Possible**

***Specifications:***

All the operations have the same priority and performed from left to right (not in *mathematically correct* order).

Comment: does the usual rules apply, like operator precedence? does the operators could be more than one in the same attempt?

Comment: all the operators have the same priority: assignment is executed from left to right. actually, operators have to repeat at least once in the same attempt because there're 3 operators and 4 "spaces" for them. btw, operators either can repeat more than once  (i.e + + + *, - - - - )

Comment: what about the numbers, are the numbers just a single digits or are the value greater than 9 for each?

Comment: assume that each number is natural and less than or equal to 50

Comment: quote "operators either can repeat more than once".....1+1+1+1+1+1+1(clipped) etc  = 23. you need to define your rules more clearly

Comment: @Seabizkit Operators may repeat, the given numbers may not.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for clearing that up

Comment: i would say brute force try all combinations is the only way? what usage would this have... or simply for fun?

Comment: @Seabizkit it's just a task from local computer science competition which I cannot resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can use brute force to try out every possible combination, i would suggest a slightly more elegant solution:

The last digit as well as multiplication is the key. If the result (23) isn't divisible by the last digit, then the last operator can't be "*". Then you can try out the same for the result +- the last digit, as it is either added or subtracted. Iterating backwards this way should save quite a few iterations.

Pseudo-Code Example:

```
var digits = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var expected = 23;
var combinatoric =  function(digits, expected) {
    var result = false;
    var digit = digits[digits.length -1];
    var nDigits = digits.removeLast();
    // If we are at the last digit...
    if(nDigits.isEmpty() && Math.abs(digit) == Math.abs(expected)) {
        //Last digit must be added or substracted, as its the starting digit.
        result = true;
    } else if(!nDigits.isEmpty()) {
        //Only if divisible is "*" an option.
        if(expected % digit == 0) {
            if(combinatoric(nDigits, expected / digit) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        // "+" and "-" are always options.
        if(combinatoric(nDigits, expected - digit) {
            result = true;
        }
        if(combinatoric(nDigits, expected + digit) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This approach saves at least a few iterations, as you dont try to multiply if it won't resolve to a natural number anyway. And by going backwards you can make this calculation recursive, as the modified expected result is passed on to every iteration.

Comment: It'd be great if you provide a pseudocode for that solution because it's not clear for me, at least. Result will never be divisible by the last digit unless it's 1 or 23 as the result (23) is the prime number.

Comment: @HMFMDBMMC He is suggesting a brute-force backwards search, and to prune the search tree when an input wouldn't be an integer

Comment: I gonna make VERY pseudo-y code, as this gets very complex

Comment: Does this make any sense?